# How to update table content in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my current SQL Database.

```
"customers"
|cust_id|cust_name         |cust_contact |
|-------|------------------|-------------|
|1      |John's Restaurant |123          |
|2      |Carlos's Pizza    |456          |
|3      |Midtown Cafe      |789          |
|4      |Selena HomeCook   |012          |

"invoice"
|inv_id     |cust_id        |amount      |
|-----------|---------------|------------|
|113        |2              |34.50       |
|114        |4              |105.90      |
|115        |1              |14.00       |
```

I am trying to make it into

```
"invoice"
|inv_id     |cust_name        |amount      |
|-----------|-----------------|------------|
|113        |Carlos's Pizza   |34.50       |
|114        |Selena HomeCook  |105.90      |
|115        |John's Restaurant|14.00       |
```

How can I do that with SQL query using update statement?

Comment: you mean to say instead of cust_id column you wants to add cust_name in invoice table?

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: @DaminiSuthar yes.

Comment: @jsotola We are migrating to a new system. So the old database structure are not compatible with the new system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add cust_name column in Invoice table. As `cust_id` must be int type of, otherwise you need to alter `cust_id` `int to varchar`.

```
ALTER TABLE invoice
  ADD cust_name varchar(250) NULL
```

And then update value in table

```
UPDATE Invoice AS I
JOIN customers AS C ON I.cust_id = C.cust_id
SET I.cust_name = C.cust_name
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
select inv_id,cust_name,amount from invoice 
left join customers on customers.cust_id = invoice.cust_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the table, use this:

```
UPDATE invoice 
SET  cust_id  = customers.cust_name 
FROM
    invoice I
INNER JOIN
    customers C
ON 
     I.cust_id = C.cust_id
```